# Samba local master browser cannot be found via broadcast

Tags: fedora, samba, selinux, centos, broadcast

I have a Samba server (CentOS 6.5, Samba 3.6.9) that acts as a local master browser for a workgroup. I issued

```
$ setenforce 0
$ service iptables stop
```

to disable SELinux and get rid of the firewall. On that host, I can do a

```
$ smbtree -d3
```

and get (among other output)

```
name_resolve_bcast: Attempting broadcast lookup for name __MSBROWSE__<0x1>
Got a positive name query response from 192.168.1.10 ( 192.168.1.10 )
```

where 192.168.1.10 is the IP address of that host.

I want to access this server from a Linux client (Fedora 20, Samba 4.1.6). When I execute

```
$ smbtree -d10
```

on the client, I get (among other output):

```
name_resolve_bcast: Attempting broadcast lookup for name __MSBROWSE__<0x1>
bind succeeded on port 0
...
async_connect failed: No such file or directory
nmbd not around
samba_tevent: EPOLL_CTL_DEL EBADF for fde[0x7f6198c435c0] mpx_fde[(nil)] fd[7] - disabling
Unable to find master browser by broadcast
```

I have `name resolve order = bcast` on both hosts. Issuing the command

```
$ smbclient -L 192.168.1.10
```

on the client shows me all the servers and tells me that 192.168.1.10 is the local master browser. There is one other server involved, a Windows Server 2008 R2 that has NetBIOS over TCP disabled and can tell me about the shares that it offers, but not about any workgroups. Furthermore, the Windows Server as well as a Laptop running Ubuntu 12.04 do not have this problem and can browse the shares of the CentOS server.

How can I configure my network such that the client finds the local master browser by broadcast?

Comment: obvious question no one has asked: is the client and server in the same subnet? (i.e. they can see each other's broadcasts) Also, both need to be running `nmbd` - server is required, client is *strongly* advised.

Comment: Yes, they are both in 192.168.1.0/24.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaceing Fedora 20 with OpenSUSE 13.1 solved the problem.